# need to run gsub on the elements of an array but not working correctly

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
=>a=["MI187","MI234"]
```

and Want

```
=>a=["187","234"]
```

but

```
=>a=["MI187","MI234"]
[19] pry(main)> a.map { |a| gsub(/MI/,'') }
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for main:Object
```

but am getting the error in the last part. What is wrong with my map call?

Comment: Tim, if each element of `a` is as in your example, and you ultimately want integers, consider `a.map { |e| e[/\d+/].to_i } => [187, 234]`.

Comment: If you don't comment, I definitely put it as an answer.. ;) Why you not ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `gsub` method on each string in your block. At the present moment you are attempting to use a locally defined `gsub` function which you have not defined.

Use:

```
> a.map { |a| a.gsub(/MI/,'') }
=> ["187", "234"]
```